# Bluemix Node-REDでスマホの位置情報を取得する方法

Tags: bluemix

Bluemix Node-REDを用いてスマホの傾きセンサーのデータを簡単に取得できるようなのですが ( http://qiita.com/Unokirori/items/faa54d4eff56f5bf652f )、位置情報をNode-Redで簡単に検出するような方法はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

OwnTracksというスマホアプリが、位置情報をMQTTで送信してくれるようで、Node-RedのMQTT InのNodeを使って、位置情報を取得することが可能です。

ご質問を見て、回答欄には書ききれなかったので、Qiitaに詳細をまとめてみたので、参考にして下さい。

http://qiita.com/mfujita/items/fb4130efb6583b54f681